# Cypher join informations from different tables into a single one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new in cypher and I'm struggling with this problem:

I have these two queries

```
MATCH (u:UserNode)-[:PROMOTER_OF*1..]->(c:UserNode)
WHERE u.promoterActualRole IN ["GOLD","RUBY","SAPPHIRE","BRONZE","EMERALD", "DIAMOND"]
    AND datetime(c.promoterStartActivity) >= datetime("2021-02-01T00:00:00Z") 
    AND datetime(c.promoterStartActivity)<= datetime("2021-05-31T23:59:59Z")
    AND c.promoterEnabled = true
    AND u.firstName="Gianvito"
WITH distinct u as user, count(c) as num_promoter
WHERE num_promoter >= 150
RETURN user.firstName as name, user.email as email, num_promoter
```

which will return me a table like this

| name | email | num_promoter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gianvito | gianvito@email.com | 1475 |

and

```
MATCH (u:UserNode)-[:PROMOTER_OF*1..]->(c:UserNode)
WHERE u.promoterActualRole IN ["GOLD","RUBY","SAPPHIRE","BRONZE","EMERALD", "DIAMOND"]
    AND datetime(c.subscriptionDate) >= datetime("2021-02-01T00:00:00Z") 
    AND datetime(c.subscriptionDate)<= datetime("2021-05-31T23:59:59Z")
    AND c.kycStatus = "OK"
    AND u.firstName="Gianvito"
WITH distinct u as user, count(c) as num_swaggy
WHERE num_swaggy >= 1
RETURN user.firstName as name, user.email as email , num_swaggy
```

| name | email | num_swaggy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gianvito | gianvito@email.com | 1820 |

I would like to merge these two results into a single table.
I was doing a Union but in this way I can only create a single table with two different rows with duplicate common information and "null" as non present value.
How can I do if I want to obtain a table like this one?

| name | email | num_promoter | num_swaggy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gianvito | gianvito@email.com | 1475 | 1820 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Neo4j 4.x or higher, you can UNION the results of the queries in a subquery, and outside of it perform a sum() to get the results into a single row per user:

```
CALL {
 MATCH (u:UserNode)-[:PROMOTER_OF*1..]->(c:UserNode)
 WHERE u.promoterActualRole IN ["GOLD","RUBY","SAPPHIRE","BRONZE","EMERALD", "DIAMOND"]
    AND datetime(c.promoterStartActivity) >= datetime("2021-02-01T00:00:00Z") 
    AND datetime(c.promoterStartActivity)<= datetime("2021-05-31T23:59:59Z")
    AND c.promoterEnabled = true
    AND u.firstName="Gianvito"
 WITH u as user, count(c) as num_promoter
 WHERE num_promoter >= 150
 RETURN user, num_promoter, 0 as num_swaggy
 
 UNION
 
 MATCH (u:UserNode)-[:PROMOTER_OF*1..]->(c:UserNode)
 WHERE u.promoterActualRole IN ["GOLD","RUBY","SAPPHIRE","BRONZE","EMERALD", "DIAMOND"]
    AND datetime(c.subscriptionDate) >= datetime("2021-02-01T00:00:00Z") 
    AND datetime(c.subscriptionDate)<= datetime("2021-05-31T23:59:59Z")
    AND c.kycStatus = "OK"
    AND u.firstName="Gianvito"
 WITH u as user, count(c) as num_swaggy
 WHERE num_swaggy >= 1
 RETURN user, 0 as num_promoter, num_swaggy
}

WITH user, sum(num_promoter) as num_promoter, sum(num_swaggy) as num_swaggy
RETURN user.firstName as name, user.email as email , num_promoter, num_swaggy
```

Also you don't need to use DISTINCT when you're performing any aggregation, since the grouping key will become distinct automatically as a result of the aggregation.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much